# Fileupload into WP7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, file-upload, isolatedstorage

I just have a "short" Question. I did a lot of research the last few hours and found out, that a Wp7 application has access to his own directory and the `IsolatedStorage`. So if I want to work with a file in my application I either have to load it into the project using the Solutionexplorer in VS, or create a file manually by code, load it into the Isolated Storage and then read out of it.

So i come to the result that it isnt possible to load a specific file, which is in an unknown directory or folder and has an unknown name from my mobile Phone (or WP7 emulator) into the App directly, right? Because there is no browsing feature or something like e.g. in the ASP.NET Webform,the `FileUploadControl`.

Is my understanding correct or do I miss something?

Comment: If it is just you playing with your phone (ie. you are not trying to write an app that will pass through the app store certification), you may want to look at: http://www.wpxbox.com/video-wo7-root-tools-permission-install-use/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot access anything that is on the phone (except music and photo lib etc) other than whats included with the app and its isolated storage area.

you can't browse the local device like you can on windows. however you can download files from the net.